How can I preview draft posts on GitHub Pages (using Jekyll)?
Before actually publishing a new post, I'd like to preview it as it would show up on the page. There is of course the preview tab when editing a file in my repo, but it does not display everything.
I know about creating a _drafts folder in my repo, or setting published: false in the front matter. The Jekyll documentation says you can then run jekyll build and jekyll serve with the --drafts or --unpublished switches.  But I don't really know what do to with that info, because if I'm not mistaken, that only applies if you work locally and enter it in your terminal or something (I don't know much about programming). How would this work online on GitHub, and if it doesn't, what alternatives are there?
Thanks.
